# How do you update the Spring boot cli url config in sts?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

For STS 3.6.1.  In preferences->Spring->Spring Boot the location is a url.  How do I update this URL from 1.1.4 to 1.1.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not point the prefs page to a http url. If you want to override the default one which is downloaded automatically, you have to download it yourself and then you can point the preference page to what you downloaded, either in its still zipped form, or unzipped and installed on your machine.

This is a limitation of the current implementation of this preference page.

There is however a 'secret' (well not really, just it was not really intended for end-user) way of overriding this default by setting a system property.

Open your STS.ini file and add a lines like these:

```
-Dspring.boot.default.version=1.1.6.RELEASE
-Dspring.boot.install.url=http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-cli/1.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-cli-1.1.6.RELEASE-bin.zip
```

Add these lines just after the -vmargs line.

This will set the default url that shows in the preference page when nothing else is defined yet.

Note that if you do this with an existing workspace, then it may not have any effect because once you have used the preference page Eclipse will save a copy of these preferences somewhere in workspace metadata and then it will no longer read this system property. So you might also have to start in a fresh workspace for the property to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

I think Kris has answered a related question (why is it a URL and how can I change it), but not quite got the sweet spot for "how do I upgrade from 1.1.4 to 1.1.6?". The answer to that question is "download 1.1.6 and point Eclipse at your downloaded file(s)". You can get the .zip distro from a Maven repo or from http://start.spring.io or from GVM or homebrew (see the Boot ref docs for instructions on how to install the CLI). It's not a URL at all when the file is local (either a folder or a zip file, as indicated by the dialog).